# Find out CPU and memory usage percent of Docker container

Tags: monitoring, docker, cpu-usage, memory-usage, containers

Say I have a single machine and I want to find out how much of the physical CPU is used when I run a container.
I am not interested in inside-container stats.

Similarly I want to find out the memory usage. I am not interested in the memory usage percent inside the container.

For example, for memory, `ps` shows 2 things things:

```
$ ps -ax -o %mem,cmd | grep router
0.7 /usr/bin/docker run --rm -p 123:456 --name=the_router ...
5.3 java -jar the-router-fat.jar -conf /usr/verticles/conf/config.json
```

Second line is actually the command I execute inside the Docker container. The first line is the command I run to start the container.

Docker stats command shows a different number:

```
$ docker stats --format "table {{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemPerc}}"
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM %
1218ee798de6        0.15%               4.85%
```

Can I assume the value Docker stats return is the memory usage of the host system?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `docker stats` to see the CPU and memory usage of docker containers. Check this question for reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956063/memory-usage-of-docker-containers